# Disable Ctrl+n in firefox or chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, key-bindings

As an emacs user, I am used to ctrl+n to go to the next line in a editor form. However, in firefox and chrome, it is binded to open a new window. How can I change this setting. BTW, I am using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hi @pyang, this question seems to be about general hardware/software and would receive better answers in stackoverflow's sibling site https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add below extension in your chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-keyboard-shortcut/aidbmcboeighgdnilpdljbedbbiocphj?hl=en

Once extension added successfully enter below link in your chrome.

chrome://extensions/shortcuts

You see Disable Keyboard Shortcuts window you can enter your shortcut key there.

Hope it work for you!

Comment: This addon does disable Ctrl+N from opening a new browser, but it disables the key binding from doing anything else as well. It still disables me from using Ctrl+N in web IDE.